# Python - for with counter

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing the index in Python for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

I wonder: does Python have something like?

```
for (i=0; i < length; i += 1){ .... }
```

Of course, I might say

```
i = 0
for item in items:
 #.....
 i += 1
```

but I think there should be something similar to `for(i = 0;...)`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, item in enumerate(items):
     print i, item
```

or use [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
for i in range(len(items)):
     print i
```

(On python 2 you'd use [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) instead).

`range()` let's you step through `i` in steps other than `1` as well:

```
>>> list(range(0, 5, 2))
[0, 2, 4]
>>> list(range(4, -1, -1))
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

You *usually* don't need to use an index for sequences though; not with the [`itertools` library](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) or the [`reversed()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed); most usecases for 'special' index value ranges are covered:

```
>>> menu = ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs', 'bacon', 'sausage', 'onions']
>>> # Reversed sequence
>>> for dish in reversed(menu):
...     print(dish)
... 
onions
sausage
bacon
eggs
ham
spam
>>> import itertools
>>> # Only every third
>>> for dish in itertools.islice(menu, None, None, 3):
...     print(dish)
... 
spam
bacon
>>> # In groups of 4
>>> for dish in itertools.izip_longest(*([iter(menu)] * 4)):
...     print(dish)
... 
('spam', 'ham', 'eggs', 'bacon')
('sausage', 'onions', None, None)
```

Comment: What if I want to do i-- instead of ++? Or make i += 4?

Comment: @AlanDert: `range()` takes a step parameter: `range(0, len(items), 4)` would step through the range with steps of 4. Negative steps work too.

Answer (score 3):

Attempt for that this is a deliberate language choice. The majority of times does loop through numbers in lower level languages, those numbers are used as indexes in a sequence. For the cases one does actually needs the numbers, one should use the `range` built-in function - which returns an iterable with the desired `range([start], end, [step])`  input values.

More often, one does need both the items of a sequence and their index, in this case, one should use the builtn `enumerate`instead:

```
for index, letter in enumerate("word"):
     print index, letter
```

And finally, in C and derived languages (Java, PHP, Javascript, C#, Objective C), the `for` Syntax is just some (very rough) syntax sugar to a while loop - and you can just write the same while loop in Python.

Instead of:
`for (start_expr, check_expr, incr_expr) { code_body}` you do:

```
start_expr
while check_expr:
    code_body
    incr_expr
```

It works exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(length):
    #do something
```

[What `range` is.](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range)